# Ubuntu: Is there a good tabbed PDF viewer?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, tabs, pdf-reader

Is there a good non-bloated PDF viewer for (Ubuntu) Linux that supports tabs?

I don't want to use Acrobat Reader because it is slow and takes much memory, and my computer isn't the fastest.  I know the alternative readers evince and foxit, but they don't support opening different PDF files in tabs. (foxit has that feature on Windows, but the Linux version 1.1, which I just tried, doesn't have it.)

For evince, I know many people would like this functionality, but they get ridiculed by Ubuntu people (see [here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/15899/)), who say that tabs are the task of a window manager. If that is the case, how can I put all evince windows into one in GNOME?

Answer (score 15):

Recently came across [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) and seems like it is the best tabbed pdf reader out there right now.

You can install it using the following commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:b-eltzner/qpdfview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qpdfview
```

**EDIT -** From Ubuntu 12.10 onwards you can just use the following command. Thanks jnns for pointing out.

```
sudo apt-get install qpdfview
```

Comment: Since Ubuntu Quantal there's also a package in the default repositories. http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/qpdfview

Comment: Why does it show links in a red box? Slightly irritating

Comment: It's a bit odd but that's how it marks urls. To disable it goto `Edit` > `Settings`. In the `Graphics` tab untick `Decorate links`

Answer (score 5):

I believe at the moment there are no tabbed pdf readers for linux (I hope they implement it into foxit linux version soon tho'). **But**, alternatively you could use for example konqueror for that matter. It has tabs, and it can read pdf. Or you could use any web browser with integrated pdf support - just strip down all of it's other unnecessary options and use it for pdf reading. =)

Answer (score 2):

I can advice you to run your favorite tabbed PDF viewer for Windows under Wine emulator. I know that FoxIt reader for Windows (3rd version) is working fine under Wine. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [apvlv](http://naihe2010.github.io/apvlv/), definitely non-bloated and supports tabs. However, it is mainly controlled through vi-like keyboard commands, so it might not be fitted for everyone’s use.